# Href in table td doesnt open out the links

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make the href working in the table tr for the IE 11. Seem others example is working but my style for the table is seem not showing well as the original style. By not working I mean nothing happens when I click on the table. Below is my code

```
echo "<div id='front_end_menu_id' style='width:auto;border:0px solid #000000;'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=0 border=0>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<a href='http://test.php'><td>";  
    echo "<td align=left style='cursor:pointer;background:#111111;height:35px;width:470px;' valign=top>";   
        echo "<table cellpadding=2  border=0 style='height:38px;border:0px solid #888888;width:470px;'  >";
        echo "<td align=center width=60><img src=images/aa.png width=50></td>";
        echo "<td><font color=#ffffff size=3 face='century gothic'>TESTING</font><br><font color=#999999 style='font-size:10px;'>Description</td>";
        echo "</table>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</td></a></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Your table element structure is off.  I recommend reading table elements for HTML first.  For example, you have an anchor link right after your opening tr element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure as to whether you can place anchor tags around a TD tag. Never the less, it appears that you have a second open TD tag before you close your first one. Try this, with the anchor inside the TD:

```
echo "<div id='front_end_menu_id' style='width:auto;border:0px solid #000000;'>";
echo "<table cellpadding='0' border='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='left' style='cursor:pointer;background:#111111;height:35px;width:470px;' valign='top'>";
echo "<a href='http://test.php'>";
echo "<table cellpadding='2'  border='0' style='height:38px;border:0px solid #888888;width:470px;'  >";
echo "<td align='center' width='60'><!-- <img src='images/aa.png' width='50'>--></td>";
echo "<td><font color='#ffffff' size='3' face='century gothic'>TESTING</font><br><font color='#999999' style='font-size:10px;'>Description</td>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div id='front_end_menu_id' style='width:auto;border:0px solid #000000;'>";
    echo "<table cellpadding=0 border=0>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";    
        echo "<td align=left style='cursor:pointer;background:#111111;height:35px;width:470px;' valign=top>";   
            echo "<table cellpadding=2  border=0 style='height:38px;border:0px solid #888888;width:470px;'  >";
            echo "<a href='http://test.php'>";
            echo "<td align=center width=60><img src=images/aa.png width=50></td>";
            echo "<td><font color=#ffffff size=3 face='century gothic'>TESTING</font><br><font color=#999999 style='font-size:10px;'>Description</td>";
            echo "</a></table>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Note:  while this *may* work **this is not valid HTML**, see :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: yes im agreed with you. Now my mozilla doesnt work on this one

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"> Hello</a></td>
```